# Does a garbage disposal and/or dishwasher need to be on a GFCI?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, gfci, dishwasher, garbage-disposal

Part of me always cringes when I turn on the garbage disposal with a wet hand, which got me thinking...  Does this thing need to be on a GFCI?  And on that same thought, does the dishwasher need to be on a GFCI?  Both currently are not and wondering if they should be to meet current code.

Comment: Just want to note that just because it looks like a normal outlet doesn't mean it isn't protected by another GFCI outlet in the same run.  For instance, on my counter top, there is only one GFCI outlet, but the other "regular" outlets are protected by it.

Comment: Keep in mind too that even if you put a GFCI on the garbage disposal outlet, the on/off switch itself may not be protected.  In that case you might want to get a GFCI switch or breaker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no requirements in National Electrical Code (NEC) that a residential disposal must be GFCI protected. However, there *may* be requirements in the installation instructions, which would make GFCI protection required.

210.8(A) requires receptacles serving the kitchen countertop to be GFCI protected. It also requires GFCI protection for receptacles within 6' of a sink, but only sinks **not** in a kitchen.

The 2014 edition added 210.8(D), which requires dwelling unit dishwashers to be GFCI protected.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 210 Branch Circuits
>
> **210.8 Ground-Fault Circuit-Interrupter Protection for Personnel**
>
> **(D) Kitchen Dishwasher Branch Circuit** GFCI protection shall be provided for outlets that supply dishwashers installed in dwelling units locations.

Comment: @diceless Please see my update. 2014 does require dishwashers to be protected.

Comment: Tester101, I agree with you.  Oddly enough the 2014 NEC handbook  has some contradictory statements. Under 210.8(6) there is a footnote that reads: Receptacles installed for disposals, dishwashers, and trash compactors are not required to be protected by GFCIs.  Yet, clearly 210.8(D) states otherwise.  Also 210.8(D) should be under 210.8.(A) but for whatever reason they gave it its own subsection.  Maybe we'll see this fixed in the 2017 NEC.

Comment: @Kris I agree it's odd that they added a subsection. Actually I initially missed it, and had to edit my post.

Comment: @Tester101 thanks for the update.  I'll have to double check but I think the dishwasher and disposal are on the same outlet/circuit.  If that is the case, I will temporally have to protect both until I can get more circuits in the kitchen.

Comment: @diceless If you're not making any changes, you don't **have** to bring anything up to current code.  Codes are *minimum* safety standards, you can always GFCI protect any circuit you want.

Comment: I already need to do some electrical work in the kitchen, just going to add this to the list.  Even though I don't have to do it, I still like to keep things up to code.

Comment: @Kris I was just looking through the 2014 NEC and I didn't see that footnote that you were referring to on a garbage disposal.  I'm seeing a split in the community between those who think it needs it and those who don't.  But from what I read I think it is required.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Brain2000,  footnotes are only in the NEC handbook to my knowledge, not the standard NEC book.  The situation with a GFCI disposal revolves around having a duplex outlet within six ft of a sink that is readily accessible because the disposal is not big enough to keep people from plugging in other stuff.  It really has nothing else to do with the kitchen counter top outlets which all are required to be GFCI protected.  This is easy to remedy by either hardwiring the disposal, or using a single yoke outlet.

Comment: @Kris There's a "handbook"!?  I had no idea.  Thank you for that information.  I guess that does make sense that you don't want someone getting in under the sink to plug something else into the 2nd receptacle.

Comment: @Brain2000, yes. If you don't mind the extra cost and weight, the handbook is packed with colorful illustrations, commentaries, and footnotes.  There's also a Kindle version. But I'd be careful taking the commentaries and footnotes as "legally viable code" as they are in fact not part of the code, but added as helpful tips and advice.

Comment: @Brain2000, Going back to the disposal-GFCI conundrum, under the two minimum required branch circuits required for kitchen countertops, kitchen wall space, dining room, pantry, or similar areas, the disposal would actually be allowed to be counted on one of the two required circuits, as long as it is under 1HP, since it is on a readily accessible kitchen wall space. Not like a builtin, secured dishwasher.  Then, one could easily GFCI protect the disposal on the load side of the countertop GFCI outlets.  Safe, convenient, and affordable me thinks.

Answer (score 2):

nec 210.8 states where GFCI are required all receptacles within 6' of a sink (to service countertops).
the exception where GFCI are not required areas not easily accessable (Behind a dishwasher, fridg) or if the device is hardwired, I have 1 inspector that wants GFCI on disposal units and several others that do not require them (hard wired)
I dont like putting them in on the disposals because they trip fairly often and I have found them not to last more than a few years and I get called back.
Their may also be local requirements for them in your area not covered in the NEC.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Dishwashers should have GFI Protection, high power, wet and in direct proximity to use of the sink, often the user will have one hand in the Dishwasher and the other on or in the sink water, and both the 2017 & 2020 NEC specifically require the same.
I always also put the Disposer on the same 20A GFI Circuit Breaker for added customer safety.
I also always push for GFI Circuit Breakers protecting Receptacles in all wet areas for durability.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the answers that have already been here for several years. Care to expand on this?